# drupal 7 category and count list

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, categories

Making my code but, not what I want

```
$query = db_select('field_data_field_job','f');
$query->distinct('field_job');
$query->fields('f',array('field_job_value'));
$query->isNotNull('field_job_value');
$query->orderBy('field_job_value', 'ASC');
$items = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
$node = node_load($node->nid);
$field = field_info_field('field_job');
echo '<ul class="chapter-list">';
foreach($items as $key=>$value) {
$item = $value->field_job_value;
$label = $field['settings']['allowed_values'][$item];
$labels = $field['settings']['allowed_values'][$item];
echo '<li class=""><a href="'.$base_url.'/jobs/'.$item.'">'.$label.' '.$labels.'</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

list of construction workers

```
  Nurse 
  Doctor
```

I want to be, category list.

```
Nurse (5)
Doctor (4)
```

Comment: sorry, **list of construction workers**
  Nurse
  Doctor

Comment: have you tried $query->groupBy('field_job_value') ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

completed :)

```
foreach($items as $key=>$value) {
$item = $value->field_job_value;
$label = $field['settings']['allowed_values'][$item];
$queryItem = db_select('field_data_field_job','f');
$queryItem->fields('f',array('field_job_value'));
$queryItem->isNotNull('field_job_value');
$queryItem->condition('field_job_value', $item, '=');
$count_query = $queryItem->countQuery()->execute()->fetchField();

echo '<li class=""><a href="'.$base_url.'/jobs/'.$item.'">'.$label.' ('.$count_query.') </a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```